# remove from 1st upper case alphabetical character to end of string and and special character

Tags: python, regex

I have a small exercise that required me to remove all special character and the 1st upper case alphabetical character to end of string except dots [.] and hyphens [-] .I tried the solution here  `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-uppercase-lowercase-special-numeric-and-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string/`
The string below example is one of the example

```py
import re

def removingUpperCaseCharacters(str):
    regex = "[A-Z]"
    return (re.sub(regex, "", str))
def removingSpecialCharacters(str):
 
    # Create a regular expression
    regex = "[^.A-Za-z0-9]"
 
    # Replace every matched pattern
    # with the target string using
    # sub() method
    return (re.sub(regex, "", str))
str = "teachert.memeCon-Leng:"
print("After removing uppercase characters:",
       removingUpperCaseCharacters(str))
print("After removing special characters:",
       removingSpecialCharacters(str))
```

The output is

```
After removing uppercase characters: teachert.memeontent-ength:
After removing special characters: teachert.memeContentLength
```

The ouput I want is

```
teachert.meme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace one of your functions as follows:

```
def removingUpperCaseCharacters(inStr):
    i = 0
    while i < len(inStr) and (ord('A') > ord(inStr[i]) or ord('Z') < ord(inStr[i])):
        i += 1
    return inStr[:i]
```

The code above iterates through the string `inStr` starting at index 0 and stopping either when it passes the end (which it knows because `i < len(inStr)` is no longer `True`, which in this case means `i == len(inStr)`) or the ASCII ordinal value of the `i`'th character `ord(inStr[i])` is in the range of ASCII values corresponding to characters `'A'` through `'Z'`, whichever condition happens first. It then returns `inStr[:i]`, which is the substring of `inStr` starting at the beginning (since there is no value to the left of the `:` within the square brackets) and ending at the index one before `i` (the value to the right of the `:` within the square brackets).

In other words, it returns the whole string `inStr` if the end is reached before encountering a character from `'A'` to `'Z'`, or it returns the left substring (or prefix) of `inStr` which ends immediately before the first character in the range `'A'` to `'Z'`.

Note that I have changed the argument name from `str` in your code to `inStr` since `str` is the name of the built-in text sequence type in Python (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Comment: wow It worked!!. Sorry but could you please explain more about your code, I am still a freshman

Comment: @cacalun12 see updated answer for additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you may do a replacement on `[^.A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Z].*$`:

```py
str = "teachert.memeCon-Leng:"
output = re.sub(r'[^.A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Z].*$', '', str)
print(output)  # teachert.meme
```

The above regex pattern will first try to remove special characters.  That failing, it will match from the first capital letter until the end of the string.